# VBA Multi-Criteria Parent-Child SumProduct

Tags: excel, vba, parent-child, user-defined-functions, sumproduct

Please help.

I'm trying to create a user defined function that will use an array as multiple criteria (Pedigree) to check for corresponding parents (Parent) and then sum their respective ranges (Sumrange).

I've managed to create code that will check if a parent is in the pedigree range which will then return a result of 1 or 0. This will not return true values if blanks verify blanks. I intend to create an array with these 1's and 0's to then SumProduct it with my Sumrange. My problem is that I am unable create an array of these 1's and 0's and SumProduct them with the Sumrange without returning a #value.

This below code doesn't include the SumProduct portion but just returns 1 or 0 based on the criteria.

```
Function ProdIfs(Parent As Range, Pedigree As Range, Sumrange As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile

Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim result As Integer
    result = 0

For Each i In Parent
For Each j In Pedigree
    If i.Value = "" Or j.Value = "" Then
        result = result
        ElseIf i.Value = j.Value Then
        result = 1: GoTo NextIteration
    End If
Next j
NextIteration:
Next i

ProdIf = result
        
End Function
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer changed following comments**

If you want to return an array, you actually have to create and populate an array in your function and make sure the return type is `Variant`.

Try this

```
Function ProdIfs(Parent As Range, Pedigree As Range, Sumrange As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim result() As Integer ' The return value must be an array
    ReDim result(1 To Parent.Rows.Count, 1 To 1) ' Assuming Parent is 1 column
    
    For i = 1 To Parent.Rows.Count
        result(i, 1) = 0 ' set to 0 by default but always good to do it explicitly
        For j = 1 To Pedigree.Rows.Count
            If Parent.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Parent.Cells(i, 1) = Pedigree.Cells(j, 1) Then
                result(i, 1) = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ProdIfs = result
            
End Function
```

Edit: following your answer

- You just need to keep a running sum.
- To make your code run faster you should read values of these ranges and process them in memory. (It is much faster than asking excel for values in cells).
- The return value should be a `Double`
- This feels like a `SumIfs` ranther than a `ProdIfs`

```
Function ProdIfs(Parent As Range, Pedigree As Range, Sumrange As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vParent As Variant:     vParent = Parent.Value
    Dim vPedigree As Variant:   vPedigree = Pedigree.Value
    Dim vSumRange As Variant:   vSumRange = Sumrange.Value
    
    ProdIfs = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vParent, 1)
        For Each v In vPedigree
            If len(v) > 0 And v = vParent(i, 1) Then
                ProdIfs = ProdIfs + vSumRange(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v
    Next i
            
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. These are great but I am not trying to count Parents in the Pedigree but to confirm if they are their and then sum another range corresponding to the children.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question. Answer updated

Comment: This new code returned a 1 or 0. I was able to change it and get it to work though for my needs though. I'll post an answer below to show what I did. If you have any recommendations to refine it I welcome the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Super Symmetry for getting this 99% of the way there.

Since the original code returned a 1 or 0, I changed the code to provide a sumproduct.

Also I've made the PedigreeRange loop through columns instead of rows to fit the way my Pedigree data is.

```
Function ProdIfs(Parent As Range, Pedigree As Range, Sumrange As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim result() As Variant
    ReDim result(1, 1 To Parent.Rows.Count)
    Dim x As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Parent.Rows.Count
        x = 0
        result(1, i) = x
        For j = 1 To Pedigree.Columns.Count
            If Parent.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Pedigree.Cells(1, j) <> "" And Parent.Cells(i, 1) = Pedigree.Cells(1, j) Then
                x = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        result(1, i) = x * Sumrange(i, 1).Value
    Next i
    
    ProdIfs = WorksheetFunction.Sum(result)
            
End Function
```

Thanks again. If there are any improvements that can be made to this please let me know.